# NHibernate concurrents threaded insertions with unique constraint

Tags: c#, multithreading, nhibernate, concurrency

I have a multi-threaded application that may do some concurrent insertions of same type of object which has a property marked as unique.

```
public class Foo(){
...
    string PropertyThatshouldBeUnique {get;set;}
...
}
```

Each thread has its own session and does :

```
Foo myFooInstance = new Foo();
myFooInstance.PropertyThatshouldBeUnique = "Bar";
myThreadSession.SaveOrUpadte(myFooInstance);
```

- I have a unique constraint on my database table that prevents the
  multiple insertions and therefore I get an exception on the second
  insert which trigger the rollback of the whole transaction (which is not good)
- Concurrents insertions can be really close (a few milliseconds)
- I haven't configure any specific [Nhibernate Concurrency strategy](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions) (not sure if this could solve my issue or which one to use)

My problem is :

**How and where in the code should I check for previously inserted Foo objects with same property value ?**

Comment: *"... trigger the rollback of the whole transaction (which is not good)"* Why do you think this is not good? What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: hi diego. It's not good because I don't want to be handling the rollback (there are many other operations performed). Ideally, I would like a process that check that the object already exists so that I don't try to insert it twice

Comment: So, what you want is to prevent doing anything when a duplicate key is about to be inserted, right? The only way to do that is with exclusive locks, which are terrible for scalability. May I ask why do you have concurrent threads regularly trying to insert with a duplicate key?

Comment: actually, what I want is performing an "update" instead of an "insert" if the object exists (which means I managed to get it before doing the second SaveOrUpdate call). The unique key can be considered as a primary key but I didn't define it like that because it's a long string and my global schema uses integer for pkeys.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this in NHibernate and not breaking your current architecture?

```
if(!Update(connection))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO foo VALUES (Bar, ...)", connection))
    {
        try
        {   
            command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }               
        catch (BlahUniqueConstraintException) // dummy exception, please replace with relevant
        {
            // very rarely will get in here
            Update(connection);
        }           
    }
}           

private bool Update(SqlConnection connection)
{
    // use update to do two things at once: find out if the record exists and also ... update
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE foo SET ... WHERE PropertyThatshouldBeUnique = 'Bar'", connection))
    {
        // if the record exists and is updated then returns 1, otherwise 0
        return command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Well you did quite explain what could be a solution to my problem. However : 1) I would like to stick with Nhibernate syntax (ie : "session.SaveOrUpdate(myObject)") and 2) the insert query is part of a transaction with many other queries so it's only executed when I perform the commit at the end of my unit of work, so basically if the exception occur, I think I would have to deal with all the other queries  that need to be performed inside the transaction

Answer (score 0):

This was posted long ago, but as I was finding myself in the same kind of situation let me tell you what solutions I've found.

For DB operations, instead of letting each threads doing the job via `Nhibernate`, they send their request to another thread which is doing a kind of a service job. It exposes some method like Insert.

Thread 1 want to insert Object1

Thread 2 want to insert Object1

They are doing something like Thread3.Insert(Object1) concurrently.

The first call `Thread3` receive, it opens a Session to the DB (costless),it checks Object1 is not in the DB with a `SELECT` and then it adds it.

The second call `Thread3` receive, even if its a nanosecond later, it does the same but stop after the `SELECT` and do nothing or send back an exception.

The cost of waiting for the first call to be processed is quite low, after all you limit your multi-threading speed by DB constraints that need to be checked (thus DB access)

It's like saying, hmmm I have 2 very fast PC and 1 low Server.

I think its more of a design question than `Nhibernate` functionality.

Synchro among threads is already complicated, but synchro of DB among threads with UnitOfWork pattern in use is a pain.

(this is one of your issue here as you dont Commit your transaction everytime you Insert)

Maybe some guru here at SO have better ideas though.